# How to bounce/reverse video playback

Tags: swift, swiftui, avfoundation, avplayer, avasset

How does snapchat ["bounce" video during playback on iOS?](https://media.giphy.com/media/2imOV3DMDB0cH6J8dV/giphy.gif) (See GIF example) It's something I've attempted for years but failed to accomplish. Theres minimal resources on this topic and no repo's that accomplish it so I have no code to share.

There is this [OLD ARTICLE](https://chrissung.com/2017/03/11/reverse-video-in-ios/) using objective-C but since I don't know objective-c i can't follow it.

Would appreciate some code samples using modern Swift/SwiftUI API's.

**UPDATE:**
Alternative, would appreciate if someone can translate the [original objective-c repo from the article](https://github.com/chrissung/CSVideoReverse) into modern swift

Comment: That Objective-C code luckily doesn't have to many obscure ObjC idioms -- I bet if you did a pass through it you might have some luck! Are there specific parts that are confusing?

Comment: Objective-C will never die, at least not sooner than we, so just embed it into project (Xcode will generate bridge for you with swift) and use it as-is.

Comment: @jnpdx or Asperi are you able to translate it to switch?